# Phototagging like in Facebook and Orkut album photos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, jquery-plugins

Is there a jQuery library or any leads on implementing that photo tagging like in Facebook and Orkut Photo albums?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any suitable plugins for this purpose. So I ended up writing myself a small plug-in to mark areas over an image based on the coordinates loaded through an XML file.

The basic code is required is:

```
<div id="imageholder">

 <!-- The main image -->
 <img src="<link to image file>" alt="Image">

 <!-- The grid tags -->
 <div class="gridtag" style="bottom: 100px; left: 106px; height: 41px; width: 41px;"/>
 <div class="gridtag" style="bottom: 300px; left: 56px; height: 100px; width: 56px;"/>

 <div class="gridtag" ...

</div>
```

And the basic CSS styling required:

```
#imageholder{
 height:500px;
 width:497px;
 position:relative;
}
div.gridtag {
 border:1px solid #F0F0F0;
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:3;
}
```

In the above the divs with class "gridtags" are added using jQuery through XML or JSON and by binding events on this divs, we can make phototagging similar in Orkut.

PS: This only one side of the phototagging, ie. if we already have the coordinates we can mark on an image and add click events, which is the part actually i wanted. :) You guys has to write code for doing the marking part of the phototagging.

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm, I found that the new version of [Img Notes](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2009/01/23/img-notes-v02-a-couple-of-bug-fixes-and-some-more/) seems to do exactly what you want.

Checkout the [Demo](http://www.sanisoft.com/downloads/imgnotes-0.2/example.html). It allows you to easily add tag notes and show them using JQuery. He also depends on the [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) jquery plugin for adding notes.

Answer (score 1):

you could try [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php) or [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/).
Not 100% the same behaviour as in Facebook, but with some tweaks, this should e possible.

Comment: At a single time I may have to show more than one location/areas :(

Comment: In Facebook, you never have more than 1 rectangle shown at any moment.

Comment: In orkut they show all the rectangles initially then fades out.

Comment: So, actually, you want it like in Orkut, and NOT like in Facebook?

Comment: Basic idea behind both are same.

Comment: basically: yes, but practically: no.

Answer (score 0):

A good and complex example of tag like functionality in facebook is
[Talking Pictures](http://apps.facebook.com/talking_pictures/), Which is a facebook application.